# AWS Lambda Function URL deployed with AWS ECR image unable to be called from localhost frontend(CRA): CORS origin request blocked

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cors, create-react-app

- Created a python lambda function with a docker image with a base image

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
```

- pushed the image to AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR)
- created a lambda function with the image that we just pushed
- enabled Function URL in the console and checked CORS

  - allowedOrigins: *
- on my local machine ran `npm run start` to start the react server

  - in App.tsx

```
try {
const response = await axios.post('the function URL', requestData)
} catch (error: any) {
 console.error(error)
}
```

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at 'Function URL'. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

In the network tab of Firefox, the options method (preflight request) is failing with a 'CORS missing allow origin'

The post request fails with a NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI

Comment: Axios tends to silently include a `Content-Type` header in requests. You'll likely need to configure CORS to allow that request header.

Comment: You were correct - Thanks. Its frustrating that there wasn't somewhere that clearly stated that I needed that particular header.

Comment: Believe me, I share your frustration. Developers tend to unjustly blame CORS, but [it's their tools that actually deserve a lot of the blame](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/).